# How to close session after stopping script with Selenium Remote Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script where I use `selenium` with the remote webdriver in order to use my personal endpoint rather than Chrome or Firefox.

My problem is that when I quit my script with Ctrl + C while it's running, the `selenium` session is not closed automatically but continues to live until the timeout period is reached (which is 30 minutes for me). Also I know that in my script I can end the session with `driver.quit()`

What I would like is to close the session as soon as the script is stopped.